# How to write the results of an hierarchical regression into an equation?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have the following result from a hierarchical model.[image]

I know how to write the equation for a multiple regression model. Is it possible to write a similar mathematical equation using the coefficients from this hierarchical regression model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If LaTeX output is OK, try `equatiomatic::extract_eq(mdl)`.

For example, on this model:

```
library(lme4)
(fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy))
equatiomatic::extract_eq(fm1)
```

I get the LaTeX:

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \operatorname{Reaction}_{i}  &\sim N \left(\alpha_{j[i]} + \beta_{1j[i]}(\operatorname{Days}), \sigma^2 \right) \\    
\left(
  \begin{array}{c} 
    \begin{aligned}
      &\alpha_{j} \\
      &\beta_{1j}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{array}
\right)
  &\sim N \left(
\left(
  \begin{array}{c} 
    \begin{aligned}
      &\mu_{\alpha_{j}} \\
      &\mu_{\beta_{1j}}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{array}
\right)
, 
\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
     \sigma^2_{\alpha_{j}} & \rho_{\alpha_{j}\beta_{1j}} \\ 
     \rho_{\beta_{1j}\alpha_{j}} & \sigma^2_{\beta_{1j}}
  \end{array}
\right)
 \right)
    \text{, for Subject j = 1,} \dots \text{,J}
\end{aligned}
$$

This particular model says that

- `Reaction` for observation $i$ (from subject $j$) is normally distributed with mean $\alpha_{j[i]} + \beta_{1j[i]}(\operatorname{Days})$ and variance $\sigma^2$
- $(\alpha_j, \beta_{1j})$, for subject $j$ is drawn from a multivariate (2-dimensional in this case) with mean vector and covariance matrix specified as above

i.e. for each subject $j$, the intercept and slope are "modified" by a subject-specific effect.

Comment: Thanks, can you please briefly explain what the different terms mean?

Comment: Sure. Do you mean the code, or part or all of the LaTeX equations?

Comment: All of the LaTeX equation. I understand the code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have updated the response body. Does that clarify things? I also advise reading through relevant parts of https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html and https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/corr_braindump.html if you are unsure of how mixed models are defined :)